# How to inherit and add more logic for MudButton

Tags: inheritance, mudblazor

I want to add more logic to MudButton to extend loading state when button on clicked

I done with this implementation but I affair this is not best practice.

I hope to receive any improve from yours. Thank you !

P/s: I get content of MudButton from this link https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Button/MudButton.razor

// MudButtonLoading.razor

```
@inherits MudButton

<MudElement @bind-Ref="@_elementReference"
            HtmlTag="@HtmlTag"
            Class="@Classname"
            Style="@Style"
            @attributes="UserAttributes"
            @onclick="OnClickHandler"
            type="@ButtonType.ToDescriptionString()"
            href="@Href"
            target="@Target"
            rel="@GetRel()"
            disabled="@disabledState"
            ClickPropagation="@ClickPropagation">
    <span class="mud-button-label">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StartIcon))
        {
            <span class="@StartIconClass">
                @if (!isProcessing)
                {
                    <MudIcon Icon="@StartIcon" Size="@(IconSize ?? Size)" Color="@IconColor" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudProgressCircular Class="ms-n1" Size="LoadingSize" Indeterminate="true" />
                }
            </span>
        }

        @if (isProcessing)
        {
            @if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StartIcon) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EndIcon))
            {
                <MudProgressCircular Class="ms-n1" Size="LoadingSize" Indeterminate="true" />
            }
        }
        @ChildContent
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EndIcon))
        {
            <span class="@EndIconClass">
                @if (!isProcessing)
                {
                    <MudIcon Icon="@EndIcon" Size="@(IconSize ?? Size)" Color="@IconColor" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <MudProgressCircular Class="ms-n1" Size="LoadingSize" Indeterminate="true" />
                }
            </span>
        }
    </span>
</MudElement>
```

// MudButtonLoading.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using MudBlazor;

namespace Sample.Client.Components.Buttons
{
    public partial class MudButtonLoading
    {
        protected bool isProcessing;
        protected bool disabledState => base.GetDisabledState() || isProcessing;

        protected override async Task OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs ev)
        {
            try
            {
                isProcessing = true;
                //StateHasChanged();
                //await Task.Delay(1);

                await base.OnClickHandler(ev);

            }
            finally
            {
                isProcessing = false;
            }
        }

        protected Size LoadingSize => IconSize ?? Size switch
        {
            Size.Small => Size.Small,
            var other => other - 1
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this.. I'm sure there's a better way (i.e. don't "re-draw" the whole button when Loading changes. I made this rather early in my razor/blazor learning cycle, but it works..) :)

```
@inherits MudButton

@if (Loading) {
    <MudButton Disabled="true" Variant="@base.Variant" Class="@base.Class" Color="@base.Color">
        <MudProgressCircular Class="ms-n1" Size="Size.Small" Indeterminate="true" />
        <MudText Class="ms-2">Processing</MudText>
    </MudButton>
} else {
    @RenderBase();
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Loading { get; set; }

    RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //base.Color = Color.Primary;
        base.Variant = Variant.Filled;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```